# Progress Dialog not dismissed after loading a page

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar

I have used progress bar to indicate page is loading in android webview. But the Progress Bar is showing for ever even after the page has been loaded completely. I used logcat for debugging which shows onPageFinished function is called.

```
     @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _dialog =ProgressDialog.show(UmlScreen.this, "", "Please wait...");
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    _dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "started");
   }
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if (_dialog != null || _dialog.isShowing()) {
            _dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("LOGCAT", "finished");
        }

   }
```

Comment: then you probably have multiple instance on the screen (more than one)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903895/how-to-show-progress-bar-on-webview

Comment: yup probably that was the case, initialization of _dialog outside helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try initialization of _dialog outside WebViewClient such as in OnCreateView method

Answer (score 0):

Because the page is not finished. May be the page have a lot of images so it is taking time to download them.
you can check it using break point. debug you code and put break point at   `super.onPageFinished(view, url);`

Comment: he already mentioned "I used logcat for debugging which shows onPageFinished function is called."

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some dummy codes.

```
webview.load(url);
dialog.show();

 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //....
    dialog.dismiss();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        try{
                if (prDialog.isShowing()|| prDialog!= null) {
                    prDialog.dismiss();
                    prDialog= null; /*** Add ***/
                }

                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }
```

Or visit...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31981161/3857542